# Get visible document range in ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is it possible to extract range of currently visible text in ace editor?
For example editor contains text with only visible part between lines

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod   tempor incididunt
--------------------------------------
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
---------------------------------------
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.
```

and `document.getVisibleRange()` returns `Range(3, 0, 9, 34)`

Comment: I don't think there is any position property on a textNode, so I'd say that it's not possible to know if it's in screen or not

Answer (score 1):

There are `renderer.layerConfig.firstRow` `renderer.layerConfig.lastRow` but they do not give column at which text is wrapped.

you could use same approach as 
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.0/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js#L989 and use session.screenToDocumentPosition() to get both row and column